I need to implement inline edit on my filamentphp 3 resource view page
I am working on Laravel 11 and Filament php3. Now I need to implement inline edit on my resource view page. In my view page I am using info list builder to show content. So in a short I need implement inline edit within info list builder. This is my page
class ViewCompetency extends ViewRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = CompetencyResource::class;

    public function infolist(Infolist $infolist): Infolist
    {
        return $infolist
            ->schema([
                Section::make('Basic Information')
                    ->schema([
                        TextEntry::make('name')
                            ->label(new HtmlString('<h2 class="text-base underline font-medium">Name</h2>'))
                            ->columnSpanFull(),
                        TextEntry::make('definition')
                            ->label(new HtmlString('<h2 class="text-base underline font-medium">Definition</h2>'))
                            ->html()
                            ->columnSpanFull(),
                        TextEntry::make('meaning')
                            ->html()
                            ->label(new HtmlString('<h2 class="text-base underline font-medium">Meaning</h2>'))
                            ->columnSpanFull(),
                    ])
                    ->columns(2),

             
         }
}

I have tried to insert custom livewire component to make inline edit but unable to do this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Filament's infolist package allows you to render a read-only list of data about a particular entity.

You can have a custom View page with a form or you can have the Infolist, but you can't have an editable Infolist, that's just how it works.
Take a look at this documentation link: Creating another View page.
